# Unable to Connect to PPTP server Debian Linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, pptp

I just set up a pptp server on Debian Linux and I can connect to the server from my iPhone when in the same network as the PPTP server. But when I leave my office network, I can't connect to the vpn. On the router, I have forwarded port 1723 for PPTP but still no luck.

Thx

Comment: You are using your routers hostname and/or IP Address when you are on the outside right?

Comment: Yes I am using my external ip to connect because I have static ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PPTP uses tcp/1723 and GRE (ip protocol 47).

How you permit GRE traffic depends on the router.  Keep in mind though that you typically can only have a single PPTP session that will work through a NAT.

Comment: I don't get how to enable gre ip 47 on a Linksys router. I do have "VPN passthru" for pptp enabled if that's what you are referring to.